# Sitecore 8 ADFS module no FedAuth cookie

Tags: sitecore-client, security, authentication, cookies

I've added the Sitecore ADFS module to Sitecore 7.2 and it works.

Using the same module on Sitecore 8 doesn't work. I can see the MSISAuth cookies from sts. When it comes to reading the `FedAuth` cookie, it always returns null `FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(out sessionToken)`.

Just an update on this question. What I worked out was that in Sitecore 8 the `OnAuthenticateRequest` method in the `WSFederationAuthenticationModule` class doesn't get fired on POST requests. It's actually in the POST request that the `SessionSecurityToken` is created which is needed for the `FedAuth` cookie. I've fixed the issue by overriding the `WSFederationAuthenticationModule` class.

Comment: i think we will need more details then above, can you also mention exact sitecore version and ADFS module version you are using? Also where your sitecore site is hosted in Azure or somewhere else?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the module mentioned at https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/modules/adfsauthenticator.aspx, I don't see CMS 8.0 listed under requirements. It only mentions 7.0 and 7.1. Might be worth checking with module authors for compatibility with 8.0.